# Calling php function from html button without page refresh

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have a php script:

```
<?php
$species = $_GET['species']
...//do things to prepare the query
$result = //result of the query.
if (isset($_GET['download'])){
    getCSV();
}

function getCSV(){
    if ($result->num_rows > 0){         
        $f = fopen("csvFile", "w");
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            fputcsv($f, $row);
        }
        fclose($f);
        echo ("downloaded");
    }
    else{
        echo ("no results to download");
    }
}
?>
```

And some html code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="window.location.href='query.php?download=true'"> Click to download as csv file </button>
```

Both the php script and the html code exist in the same file, query.php.
The php script is called from another place too, which sends the 'species' GET request to it (and several others, but I have not bothered to include them here)

I would like to call the getCSV function upon clicking the button. I do not want the page to refresh, so I am aware I should be using ajax and jquery anyway (and am aware that there are many questions that have been previously asked about using ajax for this purpose). However, the php script requires the `$_GET['species']` and other data to be passed to it, and so when I click the button (similarly if I were to use ajax), the 'species' GET variable is lost, as the other GET variables are not passed to query.php by the button. Therefore the query is populated wrongly, and the getCSV function is called on useless data.

The getCSV() function is called from query.php. At the time of calling it is possible for me to access the url of the page, and manipulate it to determine what the other GET variables aside from 'download' (e.g. 'species') are. Is it possible to call the function without having to do this though, since I have quite a few variables?

Comment: AJAX is the obvious answer.  Just pass the "species" variable to the AJAX PHP page by adding the GET header.  Like "mypage.php?species=blahblah"

Comment: cant believe i've made it this complicated. Yes, by adding &download=true on to the end of the original url (`query.php?species=blahblah` becoming `query.php?species=blahblah&download=true`) solved the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**index.php** see here

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="test"> Click to download as csv file </button>
<input type="hidden" id="val" value="true"> <!--download filename value true and false-->

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#test').click(function(){

            var val = $("#val").val();

            $.ajax({
                url: 'query.php',
                type: 'GET', // get method
                data: 'download='+val, // download get name + value go
                  success: function(data) {
                    // success
                    alert(data);
                  },
                  error: function(data) {
                    // error
                    alert(data);
                  }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**query.php** see here

```
<?php
$species = clean($_GET['download']); // clean func magic quotes fix

 if (empty($species)) {

     echo 'get name not empty';
        //  empty get name print

 }else{
    if ($species == 'true'){
        echo 'download';

        // true query code here...

    }else{
        echo 'no download';

        // error code here
    }
 }
?>
```

> Title of the article samples available on site. Before writing your search.

**I told him simply, you can adjust your system.**

*REGARDS.*

Comment: Why It doesn't work. I have just recieved alert window, and how about calling functions in query.php file???Please help!!!